# Postgresql conditional order by with multiple cases

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

So I have a working order by in Postgresql plpgsql language which looks somewhat like this:

```
....
order by (CASE WHEN _sortcol='col_1' and _sortdir='desc' THEN col_1 end) desc NULLS LAST,
         (CASE WHEN _sortcol='col_2' and _sortdir='desc' THEN col_2 end) desc NULLS LAST,
         (CASE WHEN _sortcol='col_3' and _sortdir='desc' THEN col_3 end) desc NULLS LAST,
         ......
         (CASE WHEN _sortcol='col_N' and _sortdir='asc' THEN col_N end) NULLS LAST,
         (CASE WHEN _sortcol='col_N1' and _sortdir='asc' THEN col_N1 end) NULLS LAST,
```

All is working allright, but this order by clause is a huge mess while I have a big table with lots of columns. Is there a room for any code improvement and optimisation so this code takes much smaller visual space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although dynamic SQL should be used rarely, this is case where the performance probably will be better:

```
BEGIN
  ..
  EXECUTE format('SELECT .. ORDER BY %I %s', _sortcol, 
    CASE _sortdir WHEN 'desc' THEN 'desc'
                  WHEN 'asc' THEN 'asc'
                  ELSE 'asc' END);
```

When you use dynamic SQL, then you have to think about protection against SQL injection every time. Every string parameter have to be escaped or limited to safe value only.

Comment: Hello Pavel. Thanks for reply. You are right this is not the best option since it has sql injection risk and my query has user inputs. Any ideas how to stick to parameterized query and improve my code?

Comment: If you sanitize user input, then dynamic SQL is safe - look on doc for`format` function. There is not any other way then dynamic SQL. CASE in ORDER BY in your example is pretty slow for more columns and more rows.

Comment: Can you give me a clue on sanitizing user inputs? I have always relied on parameterized queries for that.

Comment: @IvanKolyhalov - every time when you use string like query identifier, you should to use function `quote_ident` or you can use `format` function, and you can use `%I` placeholder.  For other strings you can check if the content is correct - like I did it for `_sortdir`.